# Admob does not load ads by keywords

Tags: android, admob, keyword, ads, targeting

I just integrate Admob for the first time in one of my applications. I have seen that using `AdRequest.Builder().addKeyword(String)` you may try to load ads depending on the words that are included. I have included in the latest evidence of a date of birthday and location. I have two days tried to show at least one advertisement associated with any of the words you use, but I haven't gotten anything until now. It is normal? Is there any way to show ads that have a relationship with something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide additional targeting information such as keywords and age etc and the ad network will take that into consideration when choosing ads to send your way. How they do so is entirely up to the ad network.

You don't indicate whether you are not receiving ads but expect to, or whether you are receiving ads but didn't expect to based up on the additional targeting information you have provided.

You may not be receiving ads because they are not ads for your app, in your area at this particular point in time, regardless of additional targeting info.

You may be receiving ads that you don't expect to receive (because you believe the targeting info should preclude them), because the ad network has better insight into whether this ad will be of interest to the current client.